# Airflow, avoid top level pull from SSM

Tags: jinja2, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have the following DAG, which works just fine:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.subdag import SubDagOperator
from subdags import my_subdag

data_sets = Variable.get("data_sets", deserialize_json=True).get("data")

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 1, 1),
}

with DAG(
        'myDAG',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval='00 12 * * *'
) as dag:

    ...

    for data_set in data_sets:
        subdag = SubDagOperator(
            task_id=f'{data_set}_subdag',
            subdag=my_subdag(
                parent_dag_name='myDAG',
                child_dag_name=f'{data_set}_subdag',
            ),
            ...
            default_args=default_args,
        )
        start >> subdag >> end
```

But as you can see, I am calling *Variable* at the top level, which is not best practice (the scheduler queries the secret backend every minute or so).

What can I do to make it so airflow is calling *Variable.get* only during execution? I was looking at [best practices](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.2/best-practices.html), I can't use another file ('Generating Python code with embedded meta-data') so I though maybe jinja templating could help but I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't do it differently currently. If you want to have a dynamic DAG structure based on some external sources, then you cannot do it otherwise than using Top-Level code (and following best practices).

However If you want to have N identical tasks (with some variable index) that you want to dynamically start based on some dynamic data (which seems what you want to do) when the task is executed, there is a change coming in 2.3.0 that will allow you to do that.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-42+Dynamic+Task+Mapping

Comment: Thank you. And also... Damn it! :)